# What is the correct way of initialize a builder after fetching a shared preferences value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Simple example app with an AppBar with two buttons. Title of the app and main screen changes depending on which button the user has pressed.

Let me show it to you with a picture

[image: app screens]

**What I want to achieve is to save that "state" of the icon under SharedPreferences and whenever the user opens the app again, it opens with his last choice active** (To explain myself better, if the user selects the '2' icon, closes the app and reopens it again, I want it to open like the screenshot on the right)

I have successfully done all the logic behind saving the state, changing the title and body content depending on the icon selected but I can't achieve to automatically check at start the value saved and then create the layout depending on that...

This is the main code of this screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SimpleBooleanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SimpleBooleanScreenState createState() => new SimpleBooleanScreenState();
}

class SimpleBooleanScreenState extends State<SimpleBooleanScreen> {

  //Colors of the icons so one of them looks active and the other one inactive
  Color _firstIconColor = Colors.white;
  Color _secondIconColor = Colors.grey;

  //Global variable to check if the Screen One is active
  bool isScreenOneActive = true;

  //Key Name of the variable saved in shared preferences
  String keyName = "_updateScreenOneState";

  //THE FOLLOWING METHODS ARE RELATED TO SHARED PREFERENCES
  Future<bool> loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getBool(keyName) ?? true ;
  }
  Future<bool> saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.setBool(keyName, isScreenOneActive);
  }
  setData() async {
    loadData().then((value){
      isScreenOneActive = value;
      setIconColors();
    });
  }

  //Check and set icon colors
  setIconColors() async {
    //Update the buttons with colour
    if(isScreenOneActive){
      _firstIconColor = Colors.white;
      _secondIconColor = Colors.grey;
    }
    else{
      _firstIconColor = Colors.grey;
      _secondIconColor = Colors.white;
    }
  }

  //INITIALIZE DATA
  @override
  void initState() {
    setData();
    super.initState();
  }

  //BUILD
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0XFF01579B),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon( Icons.filter_1, size: 40.0, color: _firstIconColor,),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    //Change the colors and the global variable to true
                    isScreenOneActive = true;
                    setIconColors();
                    saveData(); //Updating the Shared Preferences value with the state of isScreenOneActive
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon( Icons.filter_2,  color: _secondIconColor, size: 40.0,),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    //Change the color and the global variable to false
                    isScreenOneActive = false;
                    setIconColors();
                    saveData(); //Updating the Shared Preferences value with the state of isScreenOneActive
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
            title: AppBarText(isScreenOnePassedActive: isScreenOneActive),
          ),
          body: MainBodyView(isScreenOnePassedActive: isScreenOneActive),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Create text of the App Bar depending on the icon selected
class AppBarText extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarText({Key key, this.isScreenOnePassedActive}) : super(key: key);
  final bool isScreenOnePassedActive;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isScreenOnePassedActive) {
      return Text(
        'SCREEN ONE TITLE',
      );
    }
    else {
      return Text(
        'SCREEN TWO TITLE',
      );
    }
  }
}

//Create different Tabs depending on the icon selected
class MainBodyView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainBodyView({Key key, this.isScreenOnePassedActive}) : super(key: key);
  final bool isScreenOnePassedActive;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isScreenOnePassedActive) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('SCREEN ONE',  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
        ),
      );
    }
    else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('SCREEN TWO',  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Right now, it creates the whole builder FIRST (tabs and everything) and AFTER that, it updates the value of

```
isScreenOneActive
```

with the method called here:

```
@override
void initState() {
  setData();
  super.initState();
}
```

Ideally, that variable would be initialized like this:

```
//Global variable to check if the UPDATE icon (first one) is active
bool isScreenOneActive= fetchScreenStatusPreference() ;

//Key Name of the variable saved in shared preferences
String keyName = "_updateScreenOneState"; 

fetchScreenStatusPreference()async{
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return preferences.getBool(keyName) ?? true ;
}
```

But that doesn't work as it says: "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."

Any idea of a workaround or whats the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out why... I forgot to add the setState() inside of the setData() method.

```
setData() async {
    loadData().then((value){
      setState(() {
        isScreenOneActive = value;
        setIconColors();
      });
    });
  }
```